# Compute $ (dF)_p\big( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big)\Big |_p$

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds

Suppose  $F : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3} $ be a map given by $ F(x,y)= (u,v,w)$ s.t. $u=x, v=y, w=xy$. Now for an arbitrary point $p = (x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, I need to compute $ (dF)_p\big( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big)\Big |_p$

Here $(dF)_p$ is the differential map at $p$, i.e. , $(dF)_p : T_pN \rightarrow T_{F_p}M$ for manifolds $N$ and $M$. I don't understand how to compute it. Can someone please help me in understanding such kinds of computations in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to define the differential map of $F\colon N\to M$ is as follows.  Given $v\in T_pN$, let $\gamma\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to N$ be a curve in $N$ so that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$.  Then
\begin{equation}
dF_p(v) := \frac{d}{dt}(F\circ\gamma)|_{t=0}.
\end{equation}
So to compute $dF_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p\right)$, you should first find a curve $\gamma\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ so that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p$, and then compute $\frac{d}{dt}(F\circ\gamma)|_{t=0}$.

Given $p=(p_1,p_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, you could let $\gamma(t)=(p_1+t,p_2)$, for example, and then compute $\frac{d}{dt}(F\circ\gamma)|_{t=0}$.

Comment: So, for $F(x,y)= (x,y,xy)$, $F \circ \gamma = (p_1 + t , p_2, (p_1 + t)p_2)$. Hence. the derivative w.r.t. $t$ is $(1,0,p_2)$. Is this the correct final answer?

Comment: @user383517 That looks right to me.

Comment: Here how do you show that $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v $ ? I mean $\dot{\gamma}(0) = (1,0)$. Right? So how is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p$ equal to this?

Comment: Interpreting $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as a vector field means thinking of tangent vectors as directional derivatives.  Given $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, the directional derivative of $g$ at $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$ in the direction of $(1,0)$ is just $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(p)$, so we consider $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p$ and $(1,0)$ to be equal in $T_p(\mathbb{R}^2)$.